# Checking for certain characters in C string

Tags: c, string

When accepting command line arguments in C, is there any way to ensure that the string contains only letters (i.e., no <s>letters</s> digits or symbols) without converting to int?  Is there a built-in function for this?

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   char *input = argv[1];
   if (/* input contains anything but upper and lowercase letters */)
      return 1;
   ...
}
```

Comment: *only letters (i.e., no letters or symbols)* Does that make sense? Do you mean *no letters **and** symbols*?

Comment: Maybe 'no digits or symbols'?

Comment: @Jacob It's an `Error: Undefined identifier string`.

Answer (score 6):

For 'only letters', use `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>`.  You have to wrap it into a function, of course:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool all_alpha(const char *str)
{
    char c;

    while ((c = *str++) != '\0')
        if (!isalpha(c))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Note that `isalpha()` will return different results depending on the current locale.  You might want to use `isalnum()` (alphanumerics) instead of just alphabetics; you can be more precise with `islower()` or `isupper()`.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply scan through each character of the string and if a character is found which is not an uppercase or lowercase alphabet, break out of the loop marking a flag.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, flag;

  for (i=0, flag = 1; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (!isalpha (toupper (argv[1][i])))
    {
      flag = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (flag == 1)
    printf ("\n%s contain only alphabets\n", argv[1]);
  else
    printf ("\n%s containg other symbols excpet alphabets\n", argv[1]);

  return 0;
}
```